# Cannot insert into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql-delete

I want to insert few rows into one of the tables in my client's database. I am not able to do so.

I can perform insert, update, delete operations on other tables except this one. When I try to perform Insert, Update or Delete, it does not give error but takes infinite time to execute.

I even tried disabling all triggers and constraints.

Can anyone help ?

```
if not exists(select '' from table_name where col1='val1' and col2='Val2')
begin   
    insert into lw_code_group_ext(col1,col2,col3) values(val1,val2,val3);
end
```

Comment: are you sure it's infinite time? that's a long time to wait...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That table might be locked. That means it is being read by other processes. Try working out what can be reading this table and if you find it, use:

```
... from lw_code_group_ext with (nolock) ...
```